# How to acces further node with Vue.js objects?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm getting the following object via this code : `this.$refs.modal.$el`.
[image]

However I'd like to go further and get `firstElementChild`

But it is returning me an empty node.

Could it be that the element is not created yet?
Is there any way to wait for it?

I've found out that I could acces `this.$refs.modal.$el.childNodes` but I can't access `this.$refs.modal.$el.childNodes[Ø]` what could be the meaning of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem was that the element wasn't generated yet in the DOM.

So to listen to it proprely you simply have to use [`$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

```
        makeVisible() {
            this.$refs.modal.visible = true
            this.$nextTick(function() {
                if (this.$refs.modal.$el.firstChild.clientHeight > window.innerHeight) {
                    this.$refs.modal.$el.firstChild.style.height = "90%"
                    this.$refs.modal.$el.firstChild.style.overflowY = "scroll"
                }
            })
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use this.$refs.modal.$el.childNodes.item(0) ?

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/item)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to your problem is adding a `ref` attribute to your child element.